# Testing asp.net application on Safari with Windows

Tags: ios, asp.net, iphone, safari

I am working on ASP.NET application and I want to test how it looks on IOS device, specifically Safari browser on IPhone device. I am working on windows machine and I am not abled to install any kind of virtual machine, I tried downloading the Safari browser but I found out that Apple stopped producing Safari versions for Windows so it is behaving like a demo version, I am not able to run localhost link.
Is there a solution that does not include virtual machines or paying on websites such as BrowserStack.

I tried installing Safari on Windows machine

Comment: No, you will need a Mac with the iOS simulator or a real iOS device.  I strongly suggest the second, as the simulator isn't identical to a real device.

Comment: The short answer is no.